# Integral of radial function on on the unit ball

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm looking for a proof for the formula

$$\int_{B(0,1)}f(|x|)dx  = |S^{n-1}|\int_0^1f(r)r^{n-1}dr,$$
where $B(0,1)$ is the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x\mapsto f(|x|) $ is some integrable function on $B(0,1).$

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2):

Change variables to polar coordinates and use Fubini's theorem, you get

$$\int_{B(0,1)}f(|x|)\,dx=\int_0^1\left(\int_{S^{n-1}}f(r)r^{n-1}\,d\sigma\right)\,dr$$

where $d\sigma$ is the surface area measure on $S^{n-1}$. Then just carry out the inner integration and you get your result.

Comment: @A.MONNET no, it's not a function, it's a set.

Comment: Yes it is a set but in a previous step shouldn't we integrate on the surface of the ball of radius $r$ ?  I mean 
$I = \int_0^1 f(r)\left( \int_{S^{n-1}(0,r) }d\sigma \right)dr$

Comment: No, the space $B(0,1)\setminus\{0\}\cong (0,1]\times S^{n-1}$ because the first factor is the radial one. Omitting a single point doesn't affect anything because the integral over that point is $0$, so you (essentially, up to removing that point) have a product space and each factor is independent of the other.

Comment: so the main step is a change of coordinate ?

Comment: @a.monnett yes that's accurate

Comment: Thank you. Do we have an explicit  formula for such change of coordinate (I mean $x= \phi(\sigma, r)$) ?

Comment: @a.monnett Yes, this is the standard spherical coordinates. If you want all the sines and cosines check out Wikipedia for the full formula